# Execute project in Qt Creator as root

Tags: qt, cmake, root, sudo

I have an existing cmake project which i am opening with qtcreator. it is build successfully but the generated executable has to be run as root since it needs a connection to the eth0 interface.

I have no possibility to add these "custom build settings" (it's disabled) and if i try to

```
ssh-askpass Sudo Password | sudo -S bash /to/my/executable/file
```

i got an

```
cannot execute binary file
```

error. 
i don't want to run qtcreator as root. is there any possibility to ask for the root password while running the executable. i am pretty new to cmake and qtcreator.

i'd appreciate any help.

thanx!

Comment: I doubt that Qt Creator can process pipes correctly. It's designed to execute binaries and doesn't pass its commands through command interpreter (such as bash). Try to edit sudoers to allow executing your command without password. After that you will be able to run your program with sudo without ssh-askpass. Anyway, it's better than writing sudo password in the project configuration.

Comment: thanks...sudo mycommand works without password...but now i have a final stupid question...where do i enter the "sudo" for this command? i'd like to start the executable from within the qtcreator through pressing the "play"-button. is that possible?...please say yes! ;)

Comment: In project run settings set `/usr/bin/sudo` as the executable and the rest of the command as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a one-line file at the same location than your executable:

*Content of launcher.sh:*

```
echo "root password" | sudo -S ./executable
```

Don't forget to chmod:

```
sudo chmod a+x launcher.sh // Yeah it's dirty I know!
```

Then, launch QtCreator normally, open your project, go to the settings and create a new Run configuration. The executable should be your launcher.sh file.
Tick the checkbox "Run in terminal"